# Problems with Matlab Render

Tags: matlab, render, scatter-plot

I use this code to plot scatter points on top of an image.

```
handles.fig = figure
defaultRenderer = get(gcf, 'Renderer');
set(handles.fig, 'Renderer', 'opengl');

I = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png'));
imshow(I)
hold on
hscatter= scatter(size(I,2)*rand(1,100), size(I,1)*rand(1,100), 'r.')
set (hscatter,'SizeData',80)
```

I need to use OpenGL rendering. But here I have a problem. When I zoom the scater points leave out of the picture. Another problem is that I can not change the size of scater points. Can someone help me ?

Comment: The first problem doesn't happen in my system (R2015a, Windows)

Comment: Are you sure you aren't zooming in on an area that contains **0** scatter points?